# v-model is not defined, passing data from v-data-table to custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-model

I have a custom component fileUpload in the expansion slot of a v-data-table. After uploading files from this component, I want to update the item in the data-table. I'm trying to do this using v-model:item, but when calling the uploadFiles function, I get the error: modelItem is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

component with data tables:

```
    <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="financialDocuments"
          :single-expand="singleExpand"
          :expanded.sync="expanded"
          item-key="finDocId"
          show-expand
          disable-pagination
          :hide-default-footer="true"
          no-data-text='Geen data'
        >
        
          <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
            <v-icon large @click="deleteTutorial(item.id)">
              mdi-file-find-outline
            </v-icon>
            <v-icon large class="mr-2" @click="editTutorial(item.id)">
              mdi-file-send-outline
            </v-icon>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item }">
            <td :colspan="attachmentHeaders.length">
              <v-data-table
                :headers="attachmentHeaders"
                :items="item.attachmentPlainDtos"
                item-key="finDocId"
                disable-pagination
                :hide-default-footer="true"
                no-data-text='Geen bijlagen'
              >
                <template #item.attachment="{ item }">
                  <a target="_blank" :href="item.attachmentUri">
                    {{ item.attachmentName }}
                  </a>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:[`item.attachmentActions`]="{ item }">
                  <v-icon large @click="deleteTutorial(item.id)">
                    mdi-delete
                  </v-icon>
                </template>
              </v-data-table>
              <FileUpload v-model:modelItem="item"></FileUpload>
            </td>            
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
    ....

export default {
    name: "financialDocumentList",
    data() {
        return {
            financialDocuments: [],
            singleExpand: true,
            headers: [
                { text: "DocId", align: "start", sortable: false, value: "finDocId" },
                { text: "Omschrijving", value: "description", sortable: false },
                { text: "Relatienummer", value: "debtor.debtorCode", sortable: false },
                { text: "Afleverwijze", value: "debtor.debtorDocumentDeliveryPreference", sortable: false },
                { text: "Documenttype", value: "debtor.debtorDocumentTypePreference", sortable: false },
                { text: "Acties", value: "actions", sortable: false },
            ],
            attachmentHeaders: [
                { text: "Bijlage", align: "start", value: "attachment", sortable: false},
                { text: "Acties", value: "attachmentActions", sortable: false },
            ],
        };
    },
methods: {
   .....
```

fileUpload component:

```
export default {


props: ['modelItem'],
  name: "file-upload",
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async uploadFiles() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        await this.upload(i, this.selectedFiles[i]);
      }
    },
    upload(idx, file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var finDocId = this.modelItem.finDocId;
      FinancialDocumentDataService.upload(finDocId, file, (event) => {
      }).then((response) => {
          this.modelItem = response.data;
          return resolve(response);
      }).catch((e) => {
          return reject(e);
        });
    });
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` on components are exposed as `modelValue` (not `modelItem`). [Source](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model)

```js
...
  props: ['modelValue'],
...
```

or named like this

```html
// parent
...
  <FileUpload v-model:modelItem="item"></FileUpload>
...
```

```js
// child
...
  props: ['modelItem'],
...
```

Comment: I've altered my code but still get the same error: modelItem is not defined. Does this has to do anything with the fact that Item is not defined in the: "Data()" part of the parent?

Comment: @Sunfile yes. but no one knows when you dont paste the code.

Comment: edited it with that part of the code

Comment: @Sunfile As you said, item is not defined. I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to achieve updating one financialDocument from the financialDocuments array within the FileUpload component. So the expanded data table contains data from one financialDocument, referred to by 'item'. That why I thought binding that with v-model should work.